# Java: Converting milliseconds to HH:MM:SS

Tags: java, time

I have a value in milliseconds which I would like to covert to HH::MM:SS.fff
This is just for duration purposes.

I know there is a basic way of doing this:

```
String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - 
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
);
```

But is there a better way of doing this?
Thanks.

Comment: heard of DateFormat API ??http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Is this meant to represent a duration, or a local time? (You should see what Joda Time has to offer.)

Comment: no just for duration. no local time

Comment: @PermGenError: That may well not be appropriate. For example, if the OP wants to be able to show "70 minutes 20 seconds"

Comment: no i would like to have standard format where after 59 minutes it moves to 1 hour and 0 minutes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This math will do the trick :

```
int sec  = (int)(millis/ 1000) % 60 ;
int min  = (int)((millis/ (1000*60)) % 60);
int hr   = (int)((millis/ (1000*60*60)) % 24);
```

If you want only Minute and Second, Then :

```
int sec  = (int)(millis/ 1000) % 60 ;
int min  = (int)((millis/ (1000) / 60);
```

Comment: There is a small problem while converting to string with format (HH:MM:SS). For five minutes it shows: 0:5:0 instead of 00:05:00
How would i do that we the above calculations

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want either `Duration` or `Period` from [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net). For example:

```
import org.joda.time.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long millis = 12345678L; // Just an example
        PeriodType minutesEtc = PeriodType.time().withHoursRemoved();
        Period period = new Period(millis, minutesEtc);
        String text = String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                                    period.getMinutes(),
                                    period.getSeconds());
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

(While you can certainly just do the arithmetic by hand, I would personally try to keep it as a `Period` as far as possible.)

Comment: thanks a lot but I don't have the org.joda lib. is there no already included Java API that i could use?

Comment: @Sunny: What's stopping you from downloading Joda? It's a *much* better date/time API than anything built into Java.

Comment: I am working on a project where I don't have permission to add new APIs/Classes. Sample with existing APIs would be much appriciated

Comment: @Sunny: You should really have said so in your question. If I were you, I would work to change that attitude - NIH-syndrome is a pain in the neck.